# Why does my Javascript snippet for a module return undefined on a private variable?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to see why my JS snippet is returning undefined in the console window...

```
var myModule = (function(){

  var _myVal;

  function _setMyVal(arg){

    _myVal = arg;

  }


  return {
    myVal : _myVal,
    setMyVal : _setMyVal
  };


}());

myModule.setMyVal("ss");

console.log(myModule.myVal);
```

Because setting myModule.myVal directly actually works!

Comment: `myModule` is an IIFE which has already been invoked, setting `myVal` to `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  return {
    myVal : _myVal,
    setMyVal : _setMyVal
  };
```

You are returning the current value of `_myVal` rather than a reference to it (which is what you want). After reassigning the variable `_myVal` in your function, `myModule.myVal` is still pointing to the old value.

If you want to return a reference, you can use a getter to return it:

```
  return {
    get myVal() {return _myVal},
    setMyVal : _setMyVal
  };
```

Comment: The answer is good although I'm not keen on the 'get' keyword I haven't seen it a lot and worry it will confuse people. I have refactored to two methods as it seems more orthogonal....

The getter buries the 'get' inside the inner function.

getReferences : _getReferences,
setReferences : _setReferences

Answer (score 0):

That is just how JavaScript handles variables and object properties.

```
var x = 2;
var y = {x: x};   // at this point, y.x is set to the number two,
                  // it bears no reference to the variable x

console.log(x, y.x); // 2 2

x = 3

console.log(x, y.x); // 3 2
```